# Entity framework deadlock issue using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, deadlock

I know there are many threads for this issue but I just need to ask what is best suitable solution for my problem of entity framework deadlock issue.

Application: .Net MVC with Entity Framework 6 on SQL Server 2019.
Problem: The application is processing around 100,000 rows of a table on daily basis. The major usage is during daytime. As the entity framework is executing selects on c# entities, the insert/update either from entity or from stored proc is running into deadlocks and exception throws ad it timed out.

Possible solutions we have in mind to implement are:

1. SnapShot Isolation on Sql server: This is the easiest fix but reading articles as it comes with huge price. Current size of our database is around 2TB and if tempdb grows rapidly then we might run into other side effects that will be too much to handle.
2. Wrapping each Select of c# entities with Transaction Isolation Scope with ReadCommitted. This is feasible but needs a lot of code changes may be around 600 lines to be wrapped.
3. Convert all the Select statements of c# entities into stored procs and place a "nolock".

Along with above points can anybody please suggest or point us to the solution with the current scenario?

Comment: Not enough info to answer, I think.. 100,000 rows a *day* is quite a lightly loaded database (slightly over one row per second) - what are you doing to cause deadlocks?

Comment: We need more information. Deadlocks are very hard as it can have multiple causes. Entity framework also shouldn't need th nolock statement. Why would you wrap all select statements in custom SQL code? Do you think this will solve the issue? What if it doesn't.
I think you need a different approach. Is your architecture thread safe? How many applications/instances are trying to access the database?

Comment: We had similar issues many years ago. We tried different approaches from the code side but what actually helped - rebuilding indexes in SQL Server (thanks to experienced DBA who noticed index fragmentation issue).

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the deadlock graph, the table *and index* definitions, and share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Wrapping in a transaction is likely to make things worse. You should probably look at a method to batch up the inserts, either using a Table Valued Parameter or `SqlBulkCopy`. EF is very poor at batch commands. `NOLOCK` can cause wildly inaccurate data, avoid.